# Google DataFlow: read from Kafka and save to GCS - how to guarantee exactly-once?

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm going to create Cloud Dataflow pipeline (using Apache beam) which assumes next steps:

1. Reading messages from Kafka
2. Processing messages
3. Writing processed messages to Google Cloud Storage

I would like to commit offset to Kafka only if the message is stored in GCS succesfully, that is, implement exactly-once semantic to this flow.

How can I do it, is there any out-of-box support in KafkaIO.Read of at least any possibility to manage offsets manually?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Kafka Connect plugin for this https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-gcs/gcs_connector.html

If you prefer to not use Kafka Connect, the source is open for that plugin and you can see how exactly once is achieved. However, I'd suggest giving it a go with Connect. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thank you @dawsaw.

Would it work with Apache Beam pipeline?

Comment: It will just move messages between Kafka and GCS. I don't think it really helps if beam is a strict requirement here though you can do transforms. However the method of exactly once could work in your own beam pipeline so you could use it as an example.

Comment: It is not open source